# Configuring frame rate of Asus Xtion Pro Live

Tags: ros, resolution, asus-xtion-pro-live

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to stream my camera feed to a webpage currently using mjpeg server, but the bandwidth at the moment is a tad bit high, so I'm trying to reduce the size of the stream.

Is it possible to change the frame rate to something lower? I'm using the default (640 x 480 @ 30 Hz), and I was wondering if it is possible to reduce the frame rate to something like 15 Hz? The resolutions currently available, as far as I know, are:

```
SXGA_15Hz  - 1280x1024@15Hz
VGA_30Hz   - 640x480@30Hz
VGA_25Hz   - 640x480@25Hz
QVGA_25Hz  - 320x240@25Hz
QVGA_30Hz  - 320x240@30Hz
QVGA_60Hz  - 320x240@60Hz
QQVGA_25Hz - 160x120@25Hz
QQVGA_30Hz - 160x120@30Hz
QQVGA_60Hz - 160x120@60Hz
```

I don't really want to reduce my resolution to 320x240, and I'd love it if there was something between VGA and QVGA (maybe something like 480x360), but I don't think its possible to just create my own resolutions, right?

Is there any way around this at all, or is this constrained by the hardware?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75139/configuring-frame-rate-of-asus-xtion-pro-live/) by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 324 on 2013-08-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use [topic_tools/throttle](http://ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/throttle) and have mjpeg_server subscribe to the throttled topic.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-08-28**:
This is simple and easy to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure about openni2_camera but this:

```
<param name="camera/driver/data_skip" value="10" /> <!-- 0 is default, 10 will drop 9/10 frames -->
```

works for kinect in openni_launch. It doesnt change the frame rate but it skips frames. When you run `rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure` you may be able to find more.

Or take a look at a slightly different question [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/55689/lower-kinect-resolution-for-rgbcamera-using-openni_launch/)

---

Originally posted by [vonovak](https://answers.ros.org/users/4872/vonovak/) with karma: 88 on 2013-08-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-08-28**:
Where can I include the line on top? I'm using roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch to start my camera. I tried inserting it in the openni.launch file, but it doesn't seem to work..